basic example of genkit embed with vertex ai getting permission issue
I'm trying to use the .embed command so I can store data in vector form. Below is my barebones example, just trying to run the embed command and log the output, that's it.
I'm getting a permission error.
The goto solution here is to update the IAM permissions, as you can see I have added Vertex AI user and admin every where I can. None of these service accounts have anything to do with the example shown, but just to show that it's added, please take a look.

Here is the example I am using
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' })

const { gemini15Flash, googleAI } = require('@genkit-ai/googleai');
const { vertexAI, textEmbedding004 } = require('@genkit-ai/vertexai');

const { genkit } = require('genkit');

const ai = genkit({
    plugins: [
        vertexAI({
            location: 'us-central1'
        }),
        googleAI({
            apiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_GENAI_API_KEY
        })
    ],
    model: gemini15Flash
});

(async () => {
    try {
        const embedding = await ai.embed({
            embedder: textEmbedding004,
            content: "What's the best bet on the table"
        });

        console.log("Got the embeddings");
        console.log(embedding);

        console.log("DONE");
        process.exit(0);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error", e);
        process.exit(1);
    };
})();

The only credentials used in this example is the GENAI API KEY, which I have verified is showing up and is from the correct project. I can see the key in Credentials in console, there is not a user attached to it, but even if there were, I've added permissions for everyone.
Here is the error I'm getting
Error Error: Error from Vertex AI predict: HTTP 403: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/crapsai-72b89/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/text-embedding-004' (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "aiplatform.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "resource": "projects/crapsai-72b89/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/text-embedding-004",
          "permission": "aiplatform.endpoints.predict"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

I've verified permissions, verified projects, regenerated keys, even created new IAM users.
I'm running out of ideas here, if anyone has thoughts let me know.
